# Weird volume and issue number for an IEEE publication

Tags: publications, online-publication, ieee

I recently got a paper published in IEEE, but on IEEE Xplore it is listed to be in *volume pp, issue 99*.

What does that mean?

Comment: Could you please provide the query/ your paper?

Answer (score 2):

That is what they temporarily use for "Early online" papers that have not yet been assigned to an issue.

Answer (score 1):

This simply means the volume, number, and pages have not been assigned yet.  When your paper is selected for an issue, these will change.